# Laravel dusk, Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: laravel, selenium-webdriver

This is the code i have used but i'm getting "Element not attached to the page document" error

```
$browser->visit('/')
                      ->click('.fa-envelope')
                      ->assertSee("Mailbox")
                      ->click('.btn-info')
                      ->pause(3000)
                      ->click('.multiselect__select')
                      ->click('.multiselect__element:nth-child(2)')
                      ->click('.multiselect__element:nth-child(1)')
                      ->click('.multiselect__select')
                      ->pause(3000)
                      ->click('#app > div > aside.right-side.right-padding > div > div > section > div > div.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > section > div > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.multiselect__tags > input')
                      ->pause(3000)
                      ->element('#app > div > aside.right-side.right-padding > div > div > section > div > div.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > section > div > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > span > span')->click()
                      // ->driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 170);');
                      // $browser
                      ->click('.btn-info');
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, weird thing is that I'm getting it in a type command but when I check the screenshot of the failure it clearly typed everything correctly, did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Figured it out, I just had to wait and give the element a chance to load to the dom

Comment: Same here. Restart Tests and Error disappears. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium-webdriver-staleelementreferenceexception